# Suppose $X_n \to X$ in $L^p$. Show that E$|X^p_r| \to E|X^p|$.

Tags: probability, inequality, lp-spaces, limsup-and-liminf

Suppose $X_n \to X$ in $L^p$. Show that E$|X^p_r| \to E|X^p|$.

The proof suggested the use of Minkowski's inequality in order to get that:
$$
[E|X^p|]^{1/p} \leqslant [E(|X_n - X|^p)]^{1/p} + [E(|X^p_n|)]^{1/p}
$$ and letting n $\to \infty$, liminf $E|X^p_r| \geq E|X^p|$.

Using again Minkowski:

$$
[E|X^p_n|]^{1/p} \leqslant [E(|X_n - X|^p)]^{1/p} + [E(|X^p|)]^{1/p}
$$ ensuring that limsup $E|X^p_r| \leqslant E|X^p|$

I can't understand two things.

1. Since the Minkowski's inequality state that:
   $$
   ||f+g||_p \leqslant ||f||_p + ||g||_p
   $$
   how in this case has this been used? I thought that, in the first sentence, f = $X^p$ but I can't figure it out where is the "g".
2. Why in the two sentence do I found the liminf and the limsup respectively?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Take $f=X-X_n$ and $g=X_n$.
2. If you want to show that $a_n \to a$ and you do not know that the limit exists you show that $\lim \sup a_n \leq a$ and $\lim \inf a_n \geq a$. These two facts imply that $\lim a_n$ exists and equals $a$.

Comment: So basically you're saying that when you have just one variable/function and you'd like to use the minkowski, you can do it by adding and subtracting the same quantity?

Comment: Yes, the trick is to write $X$ as $(X-X_n)+X_n$ and apply Minkowski. @Ricter

Comment: The point is that I'd have: $ X^p= X^p_n + (X^p - X^p_n)$ but in the last term inside the bracket, the exponent is inside and not outside. So how can this happen: $ (X^p - X^p_n) =  (X - X_n)^p$

Comment: Just blindly apply Minkowski inequality with the $f$ and $g$ I have mentioned. There won't be any problem. For example $\|f\|_p=(E|X|^{p})^{1/p}$.  BTW, do not write $X^{p}$. It may not be defined. Always write $|X|^{p}$. @Ricter

Comment: I think that the solution to my last question is that, instead of writing $X^p$ as i did before, I should've done: $|X|^p = (X_n + X - X_n)^p$ but now I would have the double product, which as n goes to infinity, goes to zero by the assumption, but it's not mentioned anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

For any norm $||\cdot||$ on a vector space $V$ you have $\bigg|||x||-||y||\bigg|\leq ||x-y||$ . Which in particular means that $x\mapsto ||x||$ is a continuous function.

In particular for $L^{p}(\mu)$ spaces with the $L^{p}(\mu)$ norm $||f||_{p}=\bigg(\int |f|^{p}\,d\mu\bigg)^{\frac{1}{p}}$ you have

Now $\bigg|||X_{n}||_{p}-||X||_{p}\bigg|\leq ||X_{n}-X||_{p}\to 0$

Thus $||X_{n}||_{p}\to ||X||_{p}$

Thus $(E[|X_{n}|^{p}])^{\frac{1}{p}}\to (E[|X|^{p}])^{\frac{1}{p}}$

Which gives you that $E[|X_{n}|^{p}]\to E[|X|^{p}]$

Also by the notion of continuity, whenever you have $x_{n}\to x$ in the norm, i.e. $||x_{n}-x||\to 0$, you must have $||x_{n}||\to ||x||$ due to continuity of $f:(V,||\cdot||)\to\Bbb{R}$ such that $f(x)=||x||$.

Comment: Honestly i'm not getting it. Isn't correct the solution that I gave?

Comment: Yeah it's correct. if limsup and liminf of a sequence of real numbers exist and are equal then the limit exists and equals the common value. What they are doing is $||X_{n}-(X_{n}-X)||_{p}\leq ||X_{n}||_{p}+||X_{n}-X||_{p}$ and $||X-(X-X_{n})||\leq ||X||+||X-X_{n}||$ due to the Minkowski inequalities. Now letting $n\to\infty$ gives you the required things.

Comment: What I have done is say that you don't need the above things. The moment triangle inequality holds for a norm , you directly have that $x\mapsto ||x||$ is a continuous function from the normed vector space to $\Bbb{R}$ and thus if $||x-x_{n}||\to 0$ then $||x_{n}||\to||x||$. More precisely due to the triangle inequality $\bigg|||x||-||y||\bigg|\leq ||x-y||$ which gives you that $x\mapsto ||x||$ is actually a Lipschitz continuous function.